# What's happened with CMutablePointer and CConstPointer in Xcode Beta3?

Tags: xcode, swift, beta

What's happened with CMutablePointer and CConstPointer in Xcode Beta3?

Code that successfully compiles in Beta2 fails with the errors:

```
Use of undeclared type 'CMutablePointer'
```

Comment: Nothing, according to the Release Notes, at least.

Comment: it is gone (for a while, I assume). with some other things... :(

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't know what to do with all that questions and answers which are obsolete now :)

Answer (score 14):

Use UnsafePointer and ConstUnsafePointer respectively.

From the Release Notes:

> APIs imported from C that use C pointers are now imported with a much simpler API type 
>   structure which is more predictable, preserves const mutability in more cases, and preserves 
>   __autoreleased pointer information.  Now you will see UnsafePointer, 
>   ConstUnsafePointer, AutoreleasingUnsafePointer, etc.  Function pointers are also 
>   imported now, and can be referenced and passed around.  However, you cannot call a C 
>   function pointer or convert a closure to C function pointer type.!